# Approximation of functions and weak approximation

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Let $X,Z$ be random-vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose that there exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(X)$ and $Z$ have the same distribution.  Suppose now that $\{f_k\}_k$ is a sequence in $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ converging uniformly on compacts to $f$.  Does this mean that $f_k(X)$ converges in distribution to $Z$?

Comment: Or at-least the convergence holds in what sense?

Comment: Actually, I think you have almost sure convergence if everything is defined on the samme probability space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f_k (X) \to f(X)$ pointwise, hence in distribution; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4. Since $f(X) \sim Z$, this implies that $f_k(X)$ converges to $Z$ in distribution.

Comment: If instead $f_k$ converges weakly to $f$ then does $f(X)$ converge in distribution still to Z?

Comment: @Zorn'sLama: Weakly in which sense exactly?

Comment: $f_k$ converges to $f$ when $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is equipped with the weak$^{\star}$ topology

Comment: I don't really understand what this means. For there to be a weak-*-topology on $C(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^n)$, this vector space should be the dual space of some other space, which I don't quite see. Could you write down explicitly what you mean by $f_k$ converging to $f$ weakly? Or do you just mean pointwise convergence?